# Is $(\mathcal C \times\mathcal D )^*$ isomorphic or equal to $ \mathcal C^* \times\mathcal D^* $?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ be two categories. According to Mac Lane's' book (p. 38) *Categoires for the Working Mathematician*, the dual category of $\mathcal C\times \mathcal D$ is isomorphic to the product category $\mathcal C^*\times\mathcal D^*$. However, I think that they are the same category.

It is clear that both have they same class of objects. To show that the classes of arrows are also the same, we consider two objects $A=(C,D)$ and $A'=(C',D')$, where $C$ and $C'$ are objects of $\mathcal C$ and $D$ and $D'$ are objects of $\mathcal D$. Then, if $h$ is an arrow of $A$ to $A'$ in $(\mathcal C\times\mathcal D)^*$, it is a pair of arrows $(f,g)$, where $f:C'\rightarrow C$ in $\mathcal C$ and $g:D'\rightarrow D$ in $\mathcal D$. Then $h$ can be considered as the pair of arrows $(f,g)$, with $f:C\rightarrow C'$ in $\mathcal C^*$ and $g:D\rightarrow D'$ in $\mathcal D^*$. The proof for the converse is similar, starting with a morphism $h$ of $A$ into $A'$ in the category $\mathcal C^*\times\mathcal D^*$.

This proof leads me to the question in the title: Is $(\mathcal C \times\mathcal D )^*$ isomorphic or equal to $ \mathcal C^* \times\mathcal D^* $?

Comment: You are right that it is equal; but in a sense it relies on some specific construction for $C^{op}$. In particular some authors (I don't know of any) might say that an object $A^{op}$ is not the object $A$, or similarly with arrows. By saying "isomorphic" and not "equal", McLane makes sure that it's independent of any reasonable definition of the dual category. Moreover, equality is an evil notion, the spirit of category theory is in a sense opposed to it (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence)

Comment: @Max Yes. I'm assuming that the dual category $\mathcal^{op}$ has the same objects of the original category $\mathcal C$ and that for any two objects $A$ and $B$, $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C^*}(A,B)$ is exactly equal to  $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(B,A)$. Is in this context (which, by the way, is the definition of Mac Lane for dual category) when I say that they are equal.

Comment: Yes I know; and most authors do the same, that's why I said you were right. I was simply explaining why (at least one plausible reason why ) McLane chose to say "isomorphic" rather than "equal"

Comment: @Max: Yes yes, it was clear. Thanks for add that extra info.